# Running project takes too long when MainWindow.xaml is open - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have started an MVVM application with Entity Framework and WPF. In MainWindow.xaml I wrote this :

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMAttempt.App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="525"
        DataContext="{StaticResource StudentVM}">
```

And in App.xaml I wrote this :

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <vms:StudentVM x:Key="StudentVM" xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:MVVMAttempt.App.ViewModels"/> 
  </Application.Resources>
```

The project is working correctly. But there is one problem. When MainWindow.xaml is open on Visual Studio, the program starts to run really slowly. Also I get the following error :

> Error 1   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)    C:..MVVMAttempt\MVVMAttempt.App\App.xaml    3   9   MVVMAttempt.App

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason:** Designer is trying to initialize static resources and particularly your `ViewModel` to satisfy bindings. Then you get an exception from *Entity Framework* context initialization.

---

**How to fix:** Use `System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool` in your `ViewModel` to distinguish real life and design time initialization.

```
if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
{
      // Initialize "fake" context here
}
else
{
     // EF context initialization
}
```

This might seem as an overhead at a firs glance but if you're working with *Expression Blend* and *Visual Studio designer* it is really useful to provide some dummy data just to have an idea how your control will "look and feel" in real world.

---

Another option is to set design-time `DataContext` in `xaml` which will do the same trick:

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
d:DataContext="{<Fake/design-time data context binding>}"
```

Comment: It's a bit late but what can be a fake context?

Comment: @jason For example specific ViewModel from resources with stubbed data which will satisfy bindings so you can see your view with data inside.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, there is a problem about accessing to the database. Verify that your connection is ok. Which approach of EF do you use ?

Comment: I'm using Code-First. I'm able to do CRUD operations, so although getting an error, I'm able to do read and write to database.