# WPF application starts very slowly

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this WPF application. Whenever I open MainWindow.xaml, the xaml file opens very slowly or when I run the solution when MainWindow.xaml is open, the solution runs very slowly. How can I fix this? Here is my MainWindow.xaml :

```
 <Window x:Class="CodeFirstMVVM.App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=System"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CodeFirstMVVM.App.ViewModels"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=OgrenciView}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="900">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <Button Content="Yeni" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding EkleCommand}"/>
            <Button Content="Güncelle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="109,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding DuzenleCommand}"/>
            <Button Content="Sil" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="207,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding SilCommand}"/>
            <Button Content="Kaydet" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="777,15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding KaydetCommand}"/>
            <Label Content="AdSoyad" Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="51"/>
            <Label Content="OkulNo" Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="82"/>
            <Label Content="Sınıf" Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="113" RenderTransformOrigin="0.053,-0.231"/>
            <Label Content="Yaş" Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="144" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.053,-0.077"/>
            <TextBox Height="23" Canvas.Left="131" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Canvas.Top="51" Width="283" Name="txtAdSoyad" Text="{Binding AdSoyadUI}"/>
            <TextBox Height="23" Canvas.Left="131" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Canvas.Top="86" Width="283" Name="txtOkulNo" Text="{Binding OkulNoUI}"/>
            <TextBox Height="23" Canvas.Left="131" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Canvas.Top="117" Width="283" Name="txtSinif" Text="{Binding SinifUI}"/>
            <TextBox Height="23" Canvas.Left="131" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Canvas.Top="148" Width="283" Name="txtYas" Text ="{Binding YasUI}"/>
            <DataGrid x:Name="dg01" ItemsSource="{Binding Entities, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntity}" CanUserAddRows="False" Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="201" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding AdSoyad}" Header="AdSoyad" Width="200" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OkulNo}" Header="OkulNo" Width="50" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Sinif}" Header="Sınıf" Width="50" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Yas}" Header="Yaş" Width="50" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>

            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedEntity.Notlar}"  Canvas.Left="629" Canvas.Top="201" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                <!--  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedEntity.Notlar}" Canvas.Left="622" Canvas.Top="201" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >-->
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding NotDeger}" Header="Notlar"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>

        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is my App.xaml :

```
<Application x:Class="CodeFirstMVVM.App.App" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
              xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
  <Application.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CodeFirstMVVM.ViewModels" />
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Is that all that's in mainwindow.xaml? It's an empty page?

Comment: @NickUdell You beat me to it

Comment: For a starter try running profiler in visual studio and see if you can find any bottlenecks. But the code sample you provided is not going to be enough for us to help though!

Comment: @NickUdell I have added the complete code for mainwindow.

Comment: Three obvious options: 1, you have a lot of binding exceptions being thrown. Check your output log during execution. 2, your datagrid is taking a while to load your dataset. How big is the data set? 3, Your view model takes a long time to create itself. What's going on in the constructor for that view model?

Comment: @NickUdell There is no exceptions. Dataset is very small, there is one entry inside and I have written the constructor of the viewmodel.

Comment: There's such an answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24604859/running-project-takes-too-long-when-mainwindow-xaml-is-open-wpf
But I don't understand the fake binding here : d:DataContext="{<Fake/design-time data context binding>}"

Comment: Where is the data coming from? You could try to monitor network usage by using database profiling tools and/or Fiddler to find out how much time is spend waiting for data coming from a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a GetEntities method, adding a IsInDesignMode check seems to solve my problem :

```
protected override ObservableCollection<Student> GetEntities()
        {
            if (IsInDesignMode)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {

                _entities = new ObservableCollection<Student>(_context.Set<Student>());
                return _entities;

            }
        }
```